# When exactly do we need to use MobileCapabilityType

Tags: android, appium, desiredcapabilities

I have come across two ways to add/set capabilities.

1. `capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");`

   and
2. `capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");`

so my question is how are they different and which is used when?

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely the same thing.

Using `MobileCapabilityType` gives you all the options to choose from - Enum.
At the bottom line, typing `MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME` returns `"deviceName"`